# Replacing elements in an array (string) programmatically

Tags: d

Does D's phobos library provide a function similar to std.array.replace that can replace elements in an array via a function rather than a single value for all replacements?  For example:

```
string[] params = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"];
int pnum = 0;
string psub() {
    if (pnum < params.length)
        return params[pnum++];
    return "";
}
writeln(replace("Test 1=? 2=? 3=? 4=?", "?", psub));
```

results in **Test 1=Apple 2=Apple 3=Apple 4=Apple** when the desired result is of course **Test 1=Apple 2=Orange 3=Pear 4=**

Comment: Looks like parameters in SQL prepared statements. :) Problem is that "?" may appear in the string as something we do not want to replace. How to escape it? With "\?" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`replaceAll`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_regex.html#.replaceAll) from `std.regex`:

```
writeln(replaceAll!(s => psub())("Test 1=? 2=? 3=? 4=?", `\?`));
```

Alternatively, you could use `splitter` and ranges:

```
zip(StoppingPolicy.longest, "Test 1=? 2=? 3=? 4=?".splitter("?"), params)
    .map!(a => only(a.expand))
    .joiner()
    .joiner()
    .writeln();
```